# Why doesn't the following function work for recursive appending to a list in swi prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a list L and I need to split each element into a separate list and again append them together. This is the code I made for the same.

```
split([],[]).
split([H|T],Ls):-split(T,Ls),splist(H,[]).
make(Val,[H1|List],[H1|Res]):- make(Val,List,Res). make(Val, List,[Val|List]).
splist(H,L2):- make(Sum,[],L1),append(L1,L2,NewL).
```

When I use this code, each element of L is passed recursively from split() to splist() and made into a list L1 with single element by make(). I need append to keep concatenating L1 and L2. But it does not so so

For example, I have L=[1,2,3]. Now I need the following process to be done.

H=1, L1=[1] and L2=[1]. Next H=2, L1=[2] and L2=[1,2]. Next H=3, L1=[3] and L2=[1,2,3].

I need the output as mentioned above, but this is what my code does.

H=1, L1=[1], and L2= [1]. Next H=2, L1=[2] and L2=[2]. Next H=3, L1=[3] and L2=[3].

Comment: have you copied your code correctly and fully? what is `spterm()`?

Comment: @WillNess sorry,my mistake, it was splist()

Answer (score 1):

I can't make any sense out of your code. `make` definition is incomplete. As is, it does nothing and then fails.

Your `split` is equivalent to `split(X,[]):- reverse(X,R), maplist(spl([]),R).` with `spl(B,A):-splist(A,B).`, i.e. it tries `splist(H,[])` for each element `H` of the input list `X`, backwards, to see whether it fails or not - that's its only outcome, as the arguments are fixed - `H` and `[]`.

naming your predicates `split` and `splist` is a very bad idea - we humans are wired to distinguish words from their start, and the only different letter in these names is hidden way far near the end. IOW the two names are *very* similar, and it is very easy to misread and mistype them.

lastly, for `splist(H,L2):- make(Sum,[],L1),append(L1,L2,NewL).`, since `make` cn only fail, so will `splist`. But even if `make` were to produce something in `L1` out of thin air - `Sum` starts out uninstantiated mind you - what does it say about `L2`? That it can be appended to the list `L1`? Any list can be appended to any other, saying that is saying nothing.

?? :)